# Web scraping dynamic content with Splinter module

Tags: python, web-scraping, phantomjs, splinter

I'm struggling with scraping a table (from steamcommunity) that is dynamically loaded through js. I'm using a combination of python Splinter and headless browser Phantomjs.

Here is what I already came up with:

```
from splinter import Browser
import time
import sys

browser = Browser('phantomjs')

url = 'https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/%E2%98%85%20Karambit%20%7C%20Blue%20Steel%20(Battle-Scarred)'   

browser.visit(url)
print browser.is_element_present_by_xpath('//*[@id="market_commodity_buyreqeusts_table"]', wait_time = 5)
price_table = browser.find_by_xpath('//*[@id="market_commodity_buyreqeusts_table"]/table/tbody/tr')

print price_table
print price_table.first
print price_table.first.text
print price_table.first.value
browser.quit()
```

The first method `is_element_present_by_xpath()` ensures that the table I'm interested in is loaded. Then I try to access the rows of that table.

As I understood from Splinter documentation the `.find_by_xpath()` method returns `ElementList`, which is essentially a normal list with some aliases provided.

`Price_table` is an `ElementList` of all rows of table. The last two prints give out empty results, and I can't find any reason why text-method returns an empty string.

How could the elements of that table be accessed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried code with different browsers and always got empty `text` but I found expected data in `html`. Maybe it is only mistake in `splinter`.

```
from splinter import Browser

#browser = Browser('firefox')
#browser = Browser('phantomjs')

#browser = Browser('chrome') # executable_path='/usr/bin/chromium-browser' ??? error !!!
browser = Browser('chrome') # executable_path='/usr/bin/chromedriver' OK

url = 'https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/%E2%98%85%20Karambit%20%7C%20Blue%20Steel%20(Battle-Scarred)'   

browser.visit(url)

print(browser.is_element_present_by_xpath('//*[@id="market_commodity_buyreqeusts_table"]', wait_time = 5))

price_table = browser.find_by_xpath('//*[@id="market_commodity_buyreqeusts_table"]/table/tbody/tr')

for row in price_table:
    print('row html:', row.html)
    print('row text:', row.text) # empty ???
    for col in row.find_by_tag('td'):
        print('  col html:', col.html)
        print('  col text:', col.text) # empty ???

browser.quit()
```

Comment: thank you! I'll use .html method to extract data. What do you think, using `selenium` instead of `splinter` wouldn't be easier?

Comment: I never used `splinter` and I use  `selenium` only occasionally but they seems similar. Selenium may have more informations/tutorial on internet.

Comment: I've faced a stability issue of combination `splinter` + `phantomjs`. It works great when it scrapes 1-10 links, but when I gave it 30 links it constantly fails to find a table on a page somewhere around 24th-25th link. Do you have any idea how this can be managed? Or should I switch to `selenium`?

Comment: create new question with all informations - error message, urls, etc. But first check in SO and Google maybe someone had the same problem before. And see first HTML which you get  on this 24th-25th page - maybe there is no table, or server sends some message about bot and captcha. Or you have to wait for data generated by JavaScript. etc.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing `for i in price_table` yet? From the [code](https://github.com/cobrateam/splinter/blob/master/splinter/element_list.py#L10) it states that `ElementList` element extends python `list`. I am sure you can just iterate over `price_table`.

Edit: Also this is the first time I have heard of `splinter`, it looks like it is just an abstraction over the `selenium` python package. Maybe if you are stuck you can look at [selenium docs](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/). They are better written.

```
from splinter import Browser
import time
import sys

browser = Browser('phantomjs')

url = 'https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/%E2%98%85%20Karambit%20%7C%20Blue%20Steel%20(Battle-Scarred)'   

browser.visit(url)
print browser.is_element_present_by_xpath('//*[@id="market_commodity_buyreqeusts_table"]', wait_time = 5)
price_table = browser.find_by_xpath('//*[@id="market_commodity_buyreqeusts_table"]/table/tbody/tr')

for i in price_table:
    print i
    print i.text

browser.quit()
```